# Nuxt 3 cannot retrieve dynamic param on API GET function

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I need your help with Nuxt 3. I work with Nuxt since few years and i freshly start Nuxt 3 and I don't get it.
Nuxt 3.4.2 with firebase 9.21.0 (Vue 3.2)
I followed firebase instructions so I set my app like this and I can't pass a param to my function =>

**./lib/firebase.js =>**

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firestoreDb = getFirestore(app);
```

**./server/api/getProduct.js**

```
import { firestoreDb } from "../../lib/firebase";
import { getDocs, collection, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    try {
     const docRef = doc(firestoreDb, "cities", ???**param** ???);
     const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);     
      return docSnap.data();
    } catch(error) {
      return error
   }
})
```

**./pages/[id].vue**

```
export default {
  async setup() {
    const product = await useFetch(`/api/getProduct`, { params: { city: 'Paris'} });
  }
}
```

But I don't understand how can I retrive my param (route.params.id)
There is something I don't understand because when I try to import { firestoreDb } from "../../lib/firebase"; from a plugins or a store, I get a nuxt error telling my that I can't call those lib outside the server file.
I need some inlightment or doc link to understand how make a GET call with a param from a page to the server.

I try to make a GET call with param and I don't understant how to retrieve my param from route or what ever solution to make a call to my DB.
I can see in event.context.originalUrl: '/api/getProduct?cyty=Paris', but i feel like isn't right to get it from there.
I try readBody(event) but I got "Error: (405 HTTP method is not allowed. (/api/getProduct?city=Paris

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const city= getQuery(event).city;
```

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20938 (same question I asked)
I don't undesrtand why I can't find any documentation about this `getQuery()` method